# How to populate empty array with a method in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to populate an empty array with a declared array variable in a `computed` function. I tried this but with no luck:

```
data: {
  hashtags: []
},

computed: {
  filteredHashtags () {
    var defaultHashtags = [ '#hr', '#acc', '#sales' ];

    var fHashtags = 
     _.chain( messages )
    .pluck( 'hashtags' )
    .flatten()
    .map( 
      function ( tag ) { 
        return tag && tag.trim() ? '#' + tag : null; })
    .filter( Boolean )
    .value();  

    fHashtags = _.union( fHashtags, defaultHashtags );

    return data.hashtags = fHashtags;
  }
}
```

also, is there a better method to approach this?

Comment: Did you mean to `data.hashtags = fHashtags` instead? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm kind of new to Vue. Basically I'm assigning the value of `fHastags` to the `hashtags` in `data`. But yeah you're right. I'll make the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computed property isn't really a good use case for this, because the computed value has to be referenced in order for it to be called. Instead, just make it a method and call it the method when your Vue is created.

```
data: {
  hashtags: []
},
methods: {
  filterHashtags() {
   // commented out stuff

    // set the data property with the filtered values
    this.hashtags = fHashtags;
  }
},
created(){
  this.filterHashtags();
}
```